# Java Realm One To Many Relationship create object to a RealmList

Tags: java, android, realm, one-to-many, realm-list

So I'm trying to make a one to many relationship (surprisingly there doesn't seem to be any tutorials on how to add items, there's a lot on the schema though).
My Schema is as follows (I've not included the full thing, get and set methods are there.)

```
public class Sheet extends RealmObject {

    public static final String FIELD_SHEET_ID = "sheetID";
    @PrimaryKey
    private int sheetID;
    private RealmList<Weapon> weaponList;
}


public class Weapon extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    int weaponID;
    private String weaponName;
}
```

So currently trying to add a Weapon to the Sheet. (. deliminates)So far I've tried:

```
Number maxValue = realm.where(Weapon.class).max("weaponID");
int maxValueInt;
if (maxValue != null) {
    maxValueInt = (int) maxValue;
    maxValueInt = maxValueInt++;
} else maxValueInt = 0;
Weapon weapon = realm.createObject(Weapon.class);
weapon.setWeaponID(maxValueInt);
sheet.getWeaponList().add(weapon);
```

.

```
sheet.getWeaponList().add(new Weapon());
```

.

```
sheet.getWeaponList().add(realm.createObject(Weapon.class, maxValueInt));
```

Oh and before this gets asked each of them were in

```
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Hi Christian as it's quite long for a comment I created a gist. A comment in the gist shows the code this ran on. https://gist.github.com/scorchgid/9be4de04a3ab121ec3a436246bd20a1a

Comment: You are creating the weapon twice. First time is wrong: `Weapon weapon = realm.createObject(Weapon.class);`

Comment: You are creating the weapon twice. First time is wrong: `Weapon weapon = realm.createObject(Weapon.class);`

Comment: Is that why you posted twice XD